# Removing a certain part of a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Not sure how to do this. I have a string that I need the first part of it gone. When print(result.text) runs it prints "@PERSONSTWITTER their message" I need to remove the first part "@PERSONSTWITTER".

At first I had it remove everything from the @. I ran into a problem, the first is that the person username could be any amount of letters. (@PERSONSTWITTER2, @PERSONSTWITTER12, etc) they don't have the same amount of characters. Now I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be great!

So all I need is to isolate "their message" and not the username.

```
for s in twt:
    sn = s.user.screen_name
    m = "@%s MESSAGE" % (sn)
    s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
    #time.sleep(5)

for result in twt:
    print(result.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may filter the words starting with `@` using [**`string.startswith`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) as:

```
>>> s = "@PERSONSTWITTER their message. @ANOTHERWRITER their another message."

>>> ' '.join(word for word in s.split() if not word.startswith('@'))
'their message. their another message.'
```

Here I'm firstly splitting your sentence into words, filtering the words not starting with `@`, and then joining back again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
s = "@PERSONSTWITTER their message" 
new_s = re.sub('^\S+', '', s)[1:]
```

Output:

```
'their message'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.split()` method to convert the `string` into a `list` of `strings` formed from splitting the original at (by default) `spaces`.

Then use the `.join` method to join all the elements from index `1` on wards in the list together, separated again by a space.

```
s = "@PERSONSTWITTER their message"
' '.join(s.split()[1:])
# --> 'their message'
```

---

An alternative approach would be to just `index` the first `space` and slice from then on wards:

```
s = "@PERSONSTWITTER their message"
s[s.index(' ')+1:]
# --> 'their message'
```

*Note that we had to add `1` to the index because `strings` are zero-based*

Comment: I just tried both of your methods but I keep getting errors. Where should I implement them? The error I get is AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: @Dexter You are not operating on a `string`, you are using Tweepy's `Status Object`... google how to convert this to a string.

Comment: Okay, I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "@PERSONSTWITTER their message"
split_s = s.split(' ')
message = ' '.join( split_s[1:] )
```